# GMT DateTime string to DATE SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I wanted the below `GMT` datetime to be converted to Date in `SQL`.

Input: `Tue Mar 23 2021 17:01:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

Output: `03/23/2021`

Tried:

Query 1:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,                             'Tue Mar 23 2021 17:01:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)'),                            DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())))
```

Query 2:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET('Tue Mar 23 2021 17:01:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)', DATEPART(TZOFFSET, 
    'Tue Mar 23 2021 17:01:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time')))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time', '+00:00') ?

Comment: @jarlh MS-SQL server

Comment: This is not a happy format -- the `(Central Daylight Time)` really spoils things. SQL Server can be coaxed to parse a modified string, which is then easily converted (`SELECT CONVERT(DATE, SWITCHOFFSET(TRY_PARSE(REPLACE('Tue Mar 23 2021 17:01:00 GMT-0500', ' GMT', '') AS DATETIMEOFFSET USING 'en-US'), 0))`). `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX` could be used if we're sure the offending part always starts with `(` and can be stripped off. Note that incorporating the time zone is necessary for a correct conversion to UTC (since the date might cross a boundary, e.g. `19:01:00 GMT-0500`).